# Why is only some of my CSS being applied?

Tags: html, css

I don't know why, but no matter what I do the gray border of the SIGN UP in `tbody` won't go away. I've tried using classes (combined with the ID, so it's not a matter of importance), I've tried using pseudo classes (`:4th-child {border:none}`), and really the only thing that works is taking away the whole `border-right:1px solid gray` from the `#signup td:`, which isn't really a good option. Here is the relevant code:

HTML

```
  <div id="signup">
    <form action="" method="GET" id="form">
      <fieldset>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><label for="signupname">Sign Up</label></th>
            </tr>   
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="signupname" placeholder="Your Name"></td>
              <td><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></td>
              <td><input type="email" placeholder="Email (optional)"></td>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Sign Up"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#signup{
  height:28%;
  min-height:90px;
  background-color:seashell;
  padding-top:1px;
  margin-top:-1px;
}
#signup label{
  font:200% Corbel;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px white;
  color:maroon;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#signup table{
  margin:2% auto;
}
#signup td{
  padding:5px 50px;
  border-right:1px solid gray;
}
#signup th{
  padding:0 50px;
}
#signup input{
  font:130% Trebuchet MS;
  padding:5px 5px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what border in SIGN UP? you're missing the `/` in the closing fieldset tag, that's causing browsers to render another fieldset below

Comment: Pretty sure that you forgot a fieldset closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for nth-child is wrong

```
#signup td:nth-child(4) {
  border: none;
}
```

Or perhaps even better is to use last-child

```
#signup td:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a class in the td:

```
<td class="submitrow"><input type="submit" value="Sign Up"></td>

...

#signup td.submitrow {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the `<fieldset>` tag.
Try this:

```
  <div id="signup">
    <form action="" method="GET" id="form">
      <fieldset>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><label for="signupname">Sign Up</label></th>
            </tr>   
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input id="signupname" placeholder="Your Name"></td>
              <td><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></td>
              <td><input type="email" placeholder="Email (optional)"></td>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Sign Up"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

#signup{
  height:28%;
  min-height:90px;
  background-color:seashell;
  padding-top:1px;
  margin-top:-1px;
}
#signup label{
  font:200% Corbel;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px white;
  color:maroon;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#signup table{
  margin:2% auto;
}
#signup td{
  padding:5px 50px;
  border-right:1px solid gray;
}
#signup th{
  padding:0 50px;
}
#signup input{
  font:130% Trebuchet MS;
  padding:5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: I advise closing the input tags also `<input id="signupname" placeholder="Your Name" />`

Comment: Well if he's using the HTML5 doctype that's overkill but if it's XHTML then definitely.

Comment: The problem wasn't the fieldset, but I guess it was _a_ problem.